# Windows Server 2022 on Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: windows, nas, raspberry-pi

I want to make a simple NAS server. I don't, if possible, want to have to buy a server. I have made a NAS on my LAN before with OpenMediaVault on a Pi, but I need the flexibility and tools of Windows. I am looking to install Windows Server 2022, but 2019 or 2016 would also be fine. Can someone tell me if this is possible, and if so, how? 
 Thanks 
 I have heard of WindowsOnRaspberry, and I wonder if there is a tool like this for Windows Server? I require the Windows Server File Sharing options, because I need a custom file share type (of which I have my own .exe for that needs Server Manager, and have misplaced the source code) to be readable on all my devices. Is there a way to emulate x64_86 in a VM.

 I have seen online someone has managed to get VMWare EXSi on a Pi. I’m thinking about running some Windows Server virtual environment through Box64, but the logistics of this might be difficult

Comment: Which function should your NAS have? Just file sharing? Webserver? Install Linux on the RPi and add Samba to create network share accessible from other computers. Install Apache to get a web server. Edit your question to better describe your needs.

Comment: Which Pi version, for a start? Is it at least one of the ARM64-capable versions?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. It's a Pi 4B

Comment: Windows Server has never yet been released for ARM architecture. [see here](https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-windows-server-for-arm64/). You'll have to look to Linux or get a different hardware.

Comment: Here is [one Tutorial.](https://uk.pcmag.com/network-attached-storage/124258/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-nas-for-whole-home-file-sharing). Or just google for "NAS on raspberry pi". Theres also a tutorial from the OEM: https://www.raspberrypi.com/tutorials/nas-box-raspberry-pi-tutorial/

Comment: You might be able though to use (not Windows server but) [Windows on arm on a pi](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/install-windows-11-raspberry-pi) and create a NAS as [described here](https://history-computer.com/how-to-turn-an-old-pc-into-a-nas-server/). If this is what you want, you'll just have to R&D

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server doesn't support ARM chip architecture.

You can install Windows 10 / 11 on your Pi or buy an Intel NUC which is x86 based and install Windows Server on there if the CPU is supported.

See system requirements by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/hardware-requirements